# Redux Forms for Creating and Editing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

I am working with redux-form. I need to create a new user and update the user's information using the same form. I've made the required form to create a new user right now, but I don't know how to make it available for updating.

Form Component code:

```
class UserRegistrationForm extends PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {
    handleSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    reset: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    isLoading: PropTypes.bool,
    submitting: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  };

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      showPassword: false,
    };
  }

  showPassword = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState(prevState => ({ showPassword: !prevState.showPassword }));
  };

  onSubmit = data => {
    console.log(data);
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit, reset } = this.props;

    return (
      <Col md={12} lg={12}>
        <Card>
          <CardBody>
            <div className="card__title">
              <h5 className="bold-text">STUDENT INFORMATION</h5>
            </div>
            <form className="form form--horizontal" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <div className="form__form-group">
                <span className="form__form-group-label">First Name*</span>
                <div className="form__form-group-field">
                  <Field
                    name="name"
                    component="input"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Name"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="form__form-group">
                <span className="form__form-group-label">Last Name*</span>
                <div className="form__form-group-field">
                  <Field
                    name="surname"
                    component="input"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Surname"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="form__form-group">
                <span className="form__form-group-label">E-mail*</span>
                <div className="form__form-group-field">
                  <Field
                    name="email"
                    component="input"
                    type="email"
                    placeholder="example@mail.com"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <ButtonToolbar className="form__button-toolbar">
                <Button color="primary" type="submit" className="icon" size="sm"><SendIcon /> Submit</Button>
                <Button type="button" onClick={reset} className="icon" size="sm">
                  <CloseIcon /> Cancel
                </Button>
              </ButtonToolbar>
            </form>
          </CardBody>
        </Card>
      </Col>
    );
  }
}

export default reduxForm({
  validate,
  form: 'User_Registration_Form', // a unique identifier for this form
})(withTranslation('common')(UserRegistrationForm));
```

How can I make the form both available creating and updating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the same form for the update as well, you would need to give an initialValues state to Form. Where initial values would be the value of the student you want to edit. Initialize values would be empty when you are creating a new student.

```
UserRegistrationForm = reduxForm({
  validate,
  form: 'User_Registration_Form', // a unique identifier for this form
})(withTranslation('common')(UserRegistrationForm));
InitializeFromStateForm = connect(
  state => ({
    initialValues: studentData
  }),
)(InitializeFromStateForm)
export default UserRegistrationForm
```

An example is here https://redux-form.com/6.6.3/examples/initializefromstate/

Also in your react route file, try to maintain two routes with the same form component.

```
<Route path="/student/create" component={UserRegistrationForm} />
<Route path="/student/update/:id" component={UserRegistrationForm} />
```

So whenever you need to create, you redirect to create route and when you need to update, redirect it to update route, with an id as params.